# what is Intel ICH6-10, Series 5 and 6, Atom C2000 (Avoton/Rangeley) GPIO driver in kernel source

Tags: c, linux, gpio

So in my system running command `lsmod | grep gpio` shows only one entry and thats not gpio_mock or gpio_sim for simulation module for different kernel versions

When run it shows

```
      gpio_ich               16384  0
```

at the driver source in top of the .c file it says

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0+
/*
 * Intel ICH6-10, Series 5 and 6, Atom C2000 (Avoton/Rangeley) GPIO driver
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2010 Extreme Engineering Solutions.
 */
```

so I like to know what is this device driver, which device is it enabling, why gpio mock and simulation module in my kernel 5.13.0 is not found instead this driver is found I dont have any device attached to my system so did not know gpio pins existed on my system. WHat is this driver used for, which device? `/home/fawad/bpf/linux-5.13.1/drivers/gpio/gpio_ich.c` it looks like same as raspberry pi driver or something because platform driver type in both of these two drivers are similar

Comment: `lsmod` shows you only the loaded kernel modules. You probably need to load those others you want manually or maybe build them manually if your distribution doesn't include them by default.

Comment: The driver is `gpio-ich.c` and it's exactly for the platform in question. The connection of its pins to the real hardware should be given by the schematic of the electrical wiring. It's unclear what you are asking. The device it's used for is exactly one you possess.

Comment: @0andriy `The connection of its pins to the real hardware should be given by the schematic of the electrical wiring.` what this mean? Does it mean this driver is connecting my computer to some device attached to motherboard through gpio pins. How to find out that where my system has gpio pins or not.

Comment: Your system **has** GPIO lines. Their connections are **platform dependent**. This information you may find in the schematics of the board.

Comment: @0andriy just last question do u know the device Id and vendor id for Navidia Geforce GTX 1050 Ti gpu. I need to read pci config space for pcie slot number where device is physically plugged into motherboard and also config space for bus address